# Jquery is not sending post data to php?

Tags: php, jquery

I have problem that Jquery Post is not sending data to other page. Data is sent to LikeMail.php page by clicking image. Date is stored in the id of the image.

```
             <a href="viewProfile.php?id=<?php echo $record['user_id']; ?>"><img class="img-rounded" id="<?php echo $record['user_id']; ?>" src=" <?php echo "../shadi/images/" . $record['user_photo1'] ?>" alt=""
                     width="70%" height="20%"> </a>
```

**This is my LikeMail.php page**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
<?php

include("db.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
echo "";


}
else {
    $user1 = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//    echo $user1;


    if(isset($_POST['fname'])) {//This is being received from jquery
        $user2 = $_POST['fname'];
//$lname = $_POST['surname'];


//echo $lname;
        /*$sql = "UPDATE notification SET alert='$fname' WHERE id = '1'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
            echo "updated";*/


        $check_for_likes = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM liked WHERE user1='$user1' AND user2='$user2'");
        $numrows_likes = mysqli_num_rows($check_for_likes);
        if (false == $numrows_likes) {
            echo mysqli_error($conn);
        }

        if ($numrows_likes >= 1) {
            echo '<input type="submit" name="unlikebutton_' . '" value="Unlike" id="Unlike" class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">';


        }
        if ($numrows_likes == 0) {
            echo '<input type="submit" name="likebutton_' . '" value="Like" id="Like" class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">';
        }
    }
}?>
```

POST array with variable `fname` (Also mentioned in the comments in the code) is being received from the previous page.

**This is jquery method**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.img-rounded').click(function(){
        $.post("LikeMail.php",
            {fname: this.id},
            function(data){
                $('.respond').html(data);
            }
        );

    });

});
```

Can you please tell me that what is the bug there. I have run this jquery method on other page other than **LikeMail.php** and it runs perfectly but Jquery post is not sending data to **LikeMail.php**

Comment: Please check for any console messages!

Comment: It is empty. Nothing there

Answer (score 1):

Try to [prevent default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) that happens on `<a>` click, and *maybe* to prevent event propagation.

```
$('.img-rounded').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // not sure if needed
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("LikeMail.php",
        {fname: this.id},
        function(data){
            $('.respond').html(data);
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: I have added it.. Jquery started sends data but now anchor tag isn't working

Comment: @ZainFarooq You cannot do ajax call with waiting for result _if you go to other location in the meantime_. How would you wait for `data` and do `$('.respond').html(data);` if you went to some location by clicking the anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

If i remove the `<a>` tag, it works.

See code on https://jsfiddle.net/8ywdb7uh/ (Take a look at the console messages, it will respond with 404)

Please prevent the default behaviour

Comment: yes. First I checked code without <a> tag. It worked fine. After adding <a> tag it generated problems